# Same Icon on a folder and its nested sub folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, window, sorting, desktop-icons

[image]

Does Window 7 provide such a feature where the same Icon can be applied to folders nested folders? Even if a new folder is created it should have the same folder.

The images are shown of all folders, which in my machine are nested under a Primary folder named **academy**.

Comment: Apparently there is no native way to change more than one folder icon, but see https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-change-the-standard-folder-icon-to-another-icon/ for third-party tools.

Comment: That blogs seem quite informative. Thanks.